# Get all <tr> ID in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get all tr id and register it to jQuery array,
this is my table code:

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 10px">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tabletmpitem">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>EAN</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Old Price</th>
            <th>New Price</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbodytmpitem">
            <tr id="1"><td></td>
            <tr id="2"><td></td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How to get that all id and assign them to jQuery array?
I want to use it for check what value is exist in table row?
So what I want is get all tr id and assign them to jQuery array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Iterate over tr in tbody and push it to an array

```js
var arr = [];

$("#tbodytmpitem tr").each(function() {
  arr.push(this.id);
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 10px">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tabletmpitem">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>EAN</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Old Price</th>
        <th>New Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodytmpitem">
      <tr id="1">
        <td></td>
        <tr id="2">
          <td></td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.map()` to iterate over all the `tr` and return their IDs. Then use `$.makeArray()` to convert the result into an array.

```js
var array = $.makeArray($('tbody tr[id]').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}));
console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive" style="margin-top: 10px">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tabletmpitem">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>EAN</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Old Price</th>
        <th>New Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodytmpitem">
      <tr id="1">
        <td></td>
        <tr id="2">
          <td></td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```