# How to collect all the id values for a yadcf filtered table

Tags: forms, datatables, yadcf

I'm using **datatables** and **yadcf** to filter a table. Now I'd like to take all the table row id values, for example, and use those as arguments in a POST request. How can I "collect" the values of these ids from the result of the filters that have been applied? I've seen [this example](https://datatables.net/Release-datatables/examples/api/form.html), which doesn't seem to apply to **yadcf**, but is similar to my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the information I wanted using the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626998/get-all-tr-id-in-table). I didn't realize that jQuery will select only the visible elements, which is what I want. So, after applying the **yadcf** filter to my table it's simple to select all the tr.id values resulting from the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the submit content is only the visible row with datatables.

If you have 5 rows and after filter 2 rows, if you click on submit button with the active filter only 2 rows will be submitted.

And if, conversely, you still wanted to submit all the elements of the table despite the filtering, on the onsubmit there is a yadcf function that you just have to execute which deactivates all active filtering to submit the entire table like this :

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable( {}) ;
document.onsubmit = function(){ 
    yadcf.exResetAllFilters(table) ;  
};
```